# MKMap coordinates to image coordinates mapping

Tags: objective-c, xcode, mapkit, mkmapview

How to map current location latitude,longitude in a MKMap to a UIImageView coordinates x,y.
And then actually be able to track current location changes to resemble on image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [convertCoordinate:toPointToView:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKMapView/convertCoordinate%3atoPointToView%3a).

Comment: yeah got it. Now have to implement it more complex. problem is i have to show the point location on image correctly even when i zoom the image.